# Падение программы при открытии Activity

Tags: android, java, activity

(Java, Andriod)
Где-то в этой функции, при вызове нового активити, крашится программа. Укажите пожалуйста на проблему.

```
public void clickButton (View v) {
        EditText user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editUser);
        EditText Description = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editGift);  
        Intent intent = new Intent(PassingDataDemoActivity.this, Privet.class);
        intent.putExtra("username", user.getText().toString()); 
        intent.putExtra("gift", Description.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

LogCat:
http://pastebin.com/Ax1e8vEw

Comment: честно говоря, если хочешь получить ответ, то напиши что тебе выдает LogCat

Comment: Цитирую выложенный LogCat: "android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText" 
В layout'e активити ошибка, если не найдете сами, кидайте сюда, посмотрим.
UPD.: LogCat в следущий раз можно не весь, а только по фильтру error :)

Comment: Действительно, ошибка была в layoute'е

Answer (score 4):

судя по **LogCat**`y, ошибка в 31 строке файла с этой функцией.

суть в том, что ты пытаешься найти **View** по идентификатору, однако в XML файле у тебя задан **RelativeLayout** с таким идентификатором, но ты пытаешься его привести к типу **EditText**, что делать нельзя. поэтому вылезла **java.lang.ClassCastException**

Видимо ошибка либо здесь

> EditText user =
> (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editUser);

либо здесь

> EditText Description =
> (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editGift);

Answer (score -1):

Не может быть там ошибки, ошибка может быть в Манифесте, у самого такая ошибка, вот только интент проще открывал.